# How do I set XML_PARSE_HUGE for SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, libxml2

I have a class that extends `SoapClient`

```
class SOAPWrapper extends \SoapClient
{
    public function GetSomething(GetSomething $parameters)
    {
      return $this->__soapCall('GetSomething', array($parameters));
    }
}
```

`GetSomething` is returning something bigger than 10MB, so I get the error:

> Couldn't load from 'http://example.com/example.asmx' : Excessive depth in document: 256 use XML_PARSE_HUGE option

Which means I have to use the XML_PARSE_HUGE option, but I can't see in the [`__soapCall`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) documentation how to do that.

Where and how do I set that option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to set custom parser options for SoapClient. But the missing `XML_PARSE_HUGE` option was reported [as a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67427) and should be fixed in PHP 5.4.38, 5.5.23, and 5.6.7.